# Генерация нескольких параграфов c помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Подскажите, как правильно сделать. Мне нужно, чтобы заголовки в блоке "Другие новости" подгружались с JSON файла. Я создал скрипт, но у меня выводится только последняя новость. В чем может быть проблема?

```
function News() {
    this.photo = undefined;
    this.article = '';
    this.text = '';
}

News.prototype.renderNews = function (jQuerySelector) {
    var $newsOtherNews = $('<div />', {
        class: 'news__other-news'
    });

    $.get({
        url: './news.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        context: this,
        success: function (data) {
            // Создание таблицы других новостей
            var $contentItem = $('<div />', {
                class: 'other-news__content'
            });
            for(var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
                var $itemArticle = $('<p />', {
                    text: data.news[i].article
                });
            }
            $itemArticle.appendTo($contentItem);
            $contentItem.appendTo($newsOtherNews);
        }
    });

    jQuerySelector.append($newsOtherNews);

};

$(document).ready(function () {
    var news = new News();
    news.renderNews($('.news'));
});
```

**JSON**

```
{
  "result": "1",
  "news": [
    {
      "photo": "./img/img-news/header-background.jpg",
      "article": "Проект «Краснодог»",
      "text": "Проверка текста, который я написал и составил 1."
    },
    {
      "photo": "",
      "article": "Проект «Форум добрых дел»",
      "text": "Проверка текста, который я написал и составил 2."
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Как должно быть]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На каждой итерации цикла Вы создаете новый `$itemArticle`, так что после цикла эта переменная содержит последнее значение.

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.news.length; i++) {
  var $itemArticle = $('<p />', {
    text: data.news[i].article
  });
  $itemArticle.appendTo($contentItem);
}
```